# Find the asymptotic behavior of solutions of the equation

Tags: asymptotics, roots

Find the asymptotic behavior of solutions $y$ of the equation
$$x^5 + x^2y^2=y^6,$$
which tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $0$.

My solution: if $y=Ax^n$, then
$$x^5 + A^2x^{2+2n}=A^6x^{6n}.$$
If $2+2n\ge 5$, we should have $5=6n$, but $2+2\cdot5/6 \not> 5$.

If $2+2n< 5$, we have $2+2n=6n$, $n=1/2$; $A^2=A^6\Longrightarrow A=1$, and $y\sim \sqrt x$ when $x\to 0$.

Am I right? How to find the next terms of the expansion of $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now lets use a correction term

$$y=\sqrt x + f$$

Insert and use only the first two terms in the binomial expansion

$$x^5+x^2(x+2x^{0.5} f)=x^3+6x^{2.5}f$$

$$x^5=4x^{2.5}f$$

$$f=\frac{x^{2.5}}{4}$$

Now, you may want to insert $y=\sqrt x +\frac{x^{2.5}}{4}+f$

Adding (or multiplying) a correction term and inserting into the equation usually works well.

The order of the colors are blue orange green red

Beware, I simply guessed the 0.0275

[image]